Failed to load ApplicationContext for my JUnit test
I followed an article about JUnit testing wrote a JUnit test for my User model:
import dev.cv.taskmasterserver.entity.User;
import dev.cv.taskmasterserver.repository.UserRepository;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;

@DataJpaTest
public class UserServiceImplAnotherTest {
  @Autowired
  private UserRepository userRepository;

  private User testUser;

  @BeforeEach
  public void setUp() {
    // Initialize test data before each test method
    testUser = new User()
            .setUsername("johnDoe123")
            .setFirstName("John")
            .setLastName("Doe")
            .setPassword("f823hfas");
    userRepository.save(testUser);
  }

  @AfterEach
  public void tearDown() {
    // Release test data after each test method
    userRepository.delete(testUser);
  }

  @Test
  public void givenUser_whenSaved_thenCanBeFoundById() {
    User savedUser = userRepository.findById(testUser.getId()).orElse(null);
    assertNotNull(savedUser);
    assertEquals(testUser.getUsername(), savedUser.getUsername());
    assertEquals(testUser.getPassword(), savedUser.getPassword());
  }
}

When I run the test, I get the following error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [MergedContextConfiguration@25aeb5ac testClass = dev.francisbernas.taskmasterserver.service.UserServiceImplAnotherTest, locations = [], classes = [dev.francisbernas.taskmasterserver.TaskMasterServerApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceDescriptors = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [[ImportsContextCustomizer@c755b2 key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.SqlInitializationAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcClientAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@23941fb4, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@5d908d47, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@7d322cad, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@34be3d80, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@f0395ca5, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@4b86805d, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@5be093d3], contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]

I tried adding the annotation @SpringBootTest but it resulted on a different error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Configuration error: found multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith for test class [dev.francisbernas.taskmasterserver.service.UserServiceImplAnotherTest]: [@org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.class), @org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper.class)]


Please [edit] your question and add the full stack trace for the errors.


Ensure correct code formatting by adding a space between @Autowired and private:

 @Autowired
 private UserRepository userRepository;


Tests annotated with @DataJpaTest are transactional and roll back at the end of each test, utilizing an embedded in-memory database. If you encounter exceptions, consider specifying an in-memory database like H2 in application.yml. Alternatively, for better test handling, use @ActiveProfiles(value = "test").

When using a separate database for tests, apply @ActiveProfiles(value = "test") to the test class, which loads the DB config from src/main/resources/application-test.yml. Ensure you create this file and add the test DB configuration as a normal Spring datasource config.
Example application-test.yml content:
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bookdb
    username: USERNAME
    password: PASSWORD


Additionally, specify that active profile config is not replaced by other DB configurations. Use @AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE) on the test class.

Refined code example:
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles(value = "test")
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class UserServiceImplAnotherTest {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    private User testUser;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() { 
        testUser = new User()
                .setUsername("johnDoe123")
                .setFirstName("John")
                .setLastName("Doe")
                .setPassword("f823hfas");
        userRepository.save(testUser);
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void tearDown() {
        userRepository.delete(testUser);
    }

    @Test
    public void givenUser_whenSaved_thenCanBeFoundById() {
        User savedUser = userRepository.findById(testUser.getId()).orElse(null);
        assertNotNull(savedUser);
        assertEquals(testUser.getUsername(), savedUser.getUsername());
        assertEquals(testUser.getPassword(), savedUser.getPassword());
    }
}

For more information on @DataJpaTest, refer to Spring Boot documentation.
